# Converting data to JSON format

Tags: json, python-3.x

```py
sql_response = ('{"ID": 6, "guid": "https://royal-life.com.ua/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/woocommerce-placeholder.png", "post_name": "woocommerce-placeholder", "post_title": "woocommerce-placeholder", "post_content": "", "post_excerpt": "", "post_mime_type": "image/png"}',)
```

## I thought it would transform to json like that, but the output doesn't work.

```py
json_response = json.loads(sql_response)
```

## I want to output it with this, but it doesn't accept a tuple.

```py
for row in json_response:
    with open('sql_data_response.json', 'w') as sql_data:
        json.dump(row.json(), sql_data, indent=2)
```

Comment: If you can explain what your program is supposed to do, I can help you further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sql_response[0]` to get the first element of the tuple. Then it might work.

Comment: New problem))) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'json'

Comment: if you're trying to convert a string to JSON, you'll have to use `JSON.parse(string)`